# How can I call a JS function when the user cancels the authorization check in the Google API?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am using the Google Drive API to import user images. It’s all working fine. But I have one question: what should be done if user does not authorize the app?

By default, Google’ API redirects the page to the redirect location. But I want to do something else. For example, I want to call a function in this particular situation.

Explanation:

Steps for authorization (using OAuth 2):

1. Click on login button.
2. Go to Google to enter username and password.
3. Enter the correct username and password.
4. Click the accept button to grant permission to the app.
5. Google redirects to your server app, with or without a token.

But if the user clicks on the “cancel” button, Google redirects to the URI I passed in as the redirect URL without authorizing the app (as expected). However I want to call a javascript function in this situation.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.
I just needed to look at the redirection url I was getting. It was clearly mentioning that user has denied to authorize my app. I just needed to fetch that using $_REQUEST and it was all done.
Thank you all so much by the way to look into this.

Answer (score 0):

In step 5, the page you return (or redirect to) can have ondocumentready() code which reads the URL and does whatever you want.